# How to store field values of a django form into the default database MySQL through django models using django framework?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

```
    # forms.py
    # --------
    from django import forms

    # Create your forms here
    class _CredentialsForm(forms):
        Site_Name = forms.CharField(max_length = 10, min_length = 5, strip = True, empty_value = None, `required = True, initial = 'Title of the Site')`
        _Site_Address = forms.URLField(required = True, disabled = False)
        __UserID = forms.EmailField(max_length = 20, min_length = 10, required = True, help_text = 'What `is your user name?', initial = 'Enter UserID')`
        __Password = forms.PasswordInput(attrs = None, render_value = False)


    # models.py
    # ---------
    from django.db import models
    from PYTHON.forms import _CredentialsForm

    # Create your models here.
    class _Credentials(models):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key = False, unique = True, auto_created = True)
        site = models.CharField(_CredentialsForm.Site_Name, unique = True, blank = False, null = False)
        url = models.URLField(_CredentialsForm.Site_Address, primary_key = True, blank = False, null = `False)`
        user = models.EmailField(_CredentialsForm.__UserID, unique = True, null = False, blank = False)
        password = models.fields.forms.PasswordInput(_CredentialsForm.__Password)
```

```
    Issue:- TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
        Interpreter used:- Python 3.7.4 x64 architecture
        Packages used to create this Project:- pip 19.3.1, django 3.0.1
        IDE used: Jetbrains PyCharm CE 2019.3.1
        Target File Name: models.py and forms.py
        Application Name: PYTHON
        Project Name: DJANGO
        Virtual Environment Name: frameworks
        My Error Report is as follows when i run the command "py manage.py shell" through cli by activating the virtualenv containing the django package version 3.0.1:-

        (frameworks) E:\Observations\Vamsi_Samples\Django_Apps\PROJECTS\DJANGO>py manage.py shell
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "manage.py", line 21, in 
            main()
          File "manage.py", line 17, in main
            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
          File "E:\Observations\Frameworks\frameworks\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
            utility.execute()
          File "E:\Observations\Frameworks\frameworks\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
            django.setup()
          File "E:\Observations\Frameworks\frameworks\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
            apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
          File "E:\Observations\Frameworks\frameworks\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
            app_config.import_models()
          File "E:\Observations\Frameworks\frameworks\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
            self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
          File "E:\Observations\Frameworks\frameworks\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
          File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
          File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
          File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
          File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
          File "", line 728, in exec_module
          File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
          File "E:\Observations\Vamsi_Samples\Django_Apps\PROJECTS\DJANGO\PYTHON\models.py", line 2, in 
            from .forms import _CredentialsForm
          File "E:\Observations\Vamsi_Samples\Django_Apps\PROJECTS\DJANGO\PYTHON\forms.py", line 4, in 
            class _CredentialsForm(forms):
        TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

        (frameworks) E:\Observations\Vamsi_Samples\Django_Apps\PROJECTS\DJANGO>

        Kind attention please!==> I only create the called part of the class, but not calling part. Yet superuser is not created due to this error.
```

Comment: `password = models.fields.forms.PasswordInput` is your issue. You should only be using model fields, this should probably be a `CharField`

Comment: As you stated, if I treat the password as CharField, then at the time of deploying this project, hackers may attack the password because it is in post method while rendering the credentials from the end user. So that i just leave it as PasswordInput, so kindly explain me to protect the user id and password as well from being attacked.

Comment: There are packages that provide encrypted model fields https://pypi.org/project/django-encrypted-model-fields/

Comment: @IainShelvington Are you sure, Sir? Is it safe, if it is replaced by CharField on applying the suggested encryptions?

Comment: Using a `PasswordInput` does not prevent the data from being sent plain-text in the POST data. You need to use HTTPS so that the data is encrypted in transit and you need to use some form of encryption so that the data is encrypted at rest (in the DB)

Comment: You should also consider adding a salt to the encrypted password so that you are protected from rainbow table attacks

Comment: @IainShelvington Just now, i visited the site https://pypi.org/project/django-encrypted-model-fields/ as i noticed that django-encrypted-model-fields are compatibility support upto django-2.0 and python 3.6 only in which i am using django 3.0.1 with python 3.7.4, is there any remedy then?

Comment: @IainShelvington Thank You Sir, I understood the concept and your conversion is highly appreciated.

Comment: no problem. Security is hard and I would steer clear of trying to implement anything yourself, only because there are people that specialize in it and the speed with which new attacks are produced is crazy